# proper file path of a text file to read

Tags: java

I want to manipulate a file in my java program.The file to read must be paralled to my src folder.
What should I give as file path?

Comment: You means that the file is in your source path?

Answer (score 4):

An elaborated example might help. From your question, what I get is,

Source Path : /home/user/project1/src/
File Path : /home/user/project1/src/

If this is the case, then once you build the project, the file path is not going to remain the same. So if you say that relative path for the file to open remains the same in built code, then you can use `Class.getResourceAsStream(String path)` which returns you the `InputStream` for given file. You can then construct the `File` object using it.

Refer [this](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/getresourceasstream.html) for details.

Comment: normally i create file as File f = new File("filename").So how i can create it in this case?

Comment: To answer your question, I need to know the path of file in your built code. If your java code, from where your are reading the file, is at location /src/com/foo in jar (built code) and your file is also at the same location then the filename variable should be "/com/foo/yourfile". You can create the file using 

URL url = Class.getResource(String filePath); 

File f = new File(url.toURI());

Comment: my code is in prjfolder/src/com.xyz. And m file is in prjfolder.How to read it?

Answer (score 2):

You should have a `File` object representing your `src` folder, and then create a new `File` object using that:

```
File textFile = new File(srcFolder, relativePath);
```

How you determine `srcFolder` really depends on the context.

EDIT: If you're just trying to read a file which is present at build time, you should include it in your built jar file and use either [`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) or [`Class.getResourceAsStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) to load it at execution time.

For example, if you have this structure:

```
src\
    com\
        xyz\
            Foo.class
    data\
         input.txt
```

Then you could use `Foo.class.getResourceAsStream("/data/input.txt")` or `Foo.class.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("data/input.txt")`. Both will give you an `InputStream` you can use to load the data.

Comment: @ako: Your source code, or your built code? The built code has no record of where it was built *from*.

Comment: i want a way such that even if my proejct is copied to different pc.it shold execute.So i want to create the file in a relative path.So i want to place the file parallel to the src folder

Comment: In that case the program needs a hint on where the root directory (your src dir) is. By example in Eclipse you can execute the program giving a command-line arg to it. And you can use `${resource_loc:/project/src}` (something like that) to give that path to the program. Then you can copy this Eclipse project to another Eclipse instalation and it will work. But remember! If what you want to do is reading a resource file in execution what you have to do is what Tushar Tarkas says: read it as a resource from the class path.

Comment: @ako: What would you expect it to do if you copied your program to a machine without your source code on? I agree with @helios and Tushar: if you're trying to just read a resource file, you should embed it within your jar and use Class.getResourceAsStream.

Comment: i mean if i import entire project into different eclipe, it shold work wthouth modifing file path

Comment: evern if i  import it into a eclipse running on different machine

Comment: @ako: I've edited my answer to give an example of using `getResourceAsStream`.